# How to specify whitespace in findstr on Windows?

Tags: regex, findstr

I want to specify whitespace after a certain word (SetupAX) that I am searching in a file.

I am trying the findstr command this way -

```
   findstr /n /r "SetupAX[ \r\n\t]" XYZ.frm
```

However, this doesn't work. If I don't put the whitespace, I get results like -

```
   findstr /n /r "SetupAX" XYZ.frm

   158: If Filled() Then Call SetupAXForB
   170: SetupAXForC
   196: SetupAX          //<-- correct
   242: Call SetupAX     //<-- correct
   276: Call SetupAXN
   ...
```

How do I get around this? I only want instances of "SetupAX" and not "SetupAX...". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the end of word [matching expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx)?

```
findstr /n /r "SetupAX\>" XYZ.frm
```

Comment: Ok, one problem with this is that now things like SetupAX() also show up.

Comment: @CodeBlue with *normal* regexp it would be `SetupAX[ ]|$`, but findstr doesnt' support alternatives (`|`). So you need to search twice: `'SetupAX "` and `"SetupAX$"`

Comment: @kirilloid Make this an answer and I will "accept" it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the /c option. Like this:

```
findstr /M /S /I /c:"some sentence with spaces" *.*
```

Answer (score 0):

`findstr -n -r -c:"SetupAX[ \r\n\t]"` works only partially. It doesn't match neither `\n` nor `\r`.

With *normal* regular expressions it could be written as `SetupAX[ ]|$`, but findstr doesnt' support alternatives (`|`). So you need to search twice: 'SetupAX " and "SetupAX$"

Comment: Ok, `\r\n` actually doesn't work. It is only possible to match the end of line with `$`, but it doesn't work inside `[]`